# Finding the value of the square of the Gauss sum

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

While finding the value of the square of the Gauss sum $G^2$, at some point we make a substitution as follows:
$$G^2 = \sum_{m_1=1}^{q-1}\sum_{m_2=1}^{q-1} \left(\frac{m_1 m_2}{q}\right) e_q(m_1+m_2) = \sum_{m_1=1}^{q-1}\sum_{n=1}^{q-1} \left(\frac{n}{q}\right) e_q(m_1+m_1 n),$$
where $$m_2 \equiv m_1 n\pmod q.$$
I understand that by the equivalence condition, the terms of the inner sum are one by one equal after the substitution. But I do not understand how we are allowed to interchange the variable of the inner sum from $m_2 = 1$ to $q-1$ to $n = 1$ to $q-1$  by just having $m_2 \equiv m_1 n \pmod q$. Note: Here, $q$ is a prime.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you understand why the terms are equal, what could be the problem? It's a finite sum – there's no issue of rearranging an infinite series. You're just summing over the same finitely many terms, so you'll get the same sum.

Comment: Ah, perhaps I see – you're asking why the condition $m_2\equiv m_1n\pmod q$ is fulfilled once for each $m_2$ when $n$ runs from $1$ to $q-1$? That's because the multiplicative group modulo $q$ is a group.

Comment: Yes, I meant that! But I guess I am still missing something. It seems to me like we have to have $m_2 \equiv m_1 (q)$, $m_2 \equiv 2 m_1 (q)$, $m_2 \equiv 3 m_1 (q)$ which simply does not make sense. But maybe you are saying we have a value of $m_2$ for each such equivalence relation? Which property of groups we need to consider here?

Comment: Do we take the group inverse each time and have $m_2 \equiv m_1 (q)$, $2^{-1} m_2 \equiv m_1 (q)$, $3^{-1} m_2 \equiv m_1 (q)$ and so on?

Comment: Yes, it's related to the group inverse (see my answer), but I don't know why you're solving the equations for $m_1$. We're switching the sum from $m_2$ to $n$, so $m_1$ is fixed and you can get $m_2$ from $m$ using $m_2\equiv m_1n\pmod q$ or $n$ from $m_2$ using $n\equiv m_1^{-1}m_2\pmod q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the sum over $m_2$ can be replaced by a sum over $n$ because by the group properties of the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_q^\times$ the equation

$$
m_2=m_1n\pmod q
$$

establishes a bijection between the values of $m_2$ and $n$. For a given value of $m_2$, the corresponding value of $n$ is $m_1^{-1}m_2$.